# py4j.Py4JException: Method and([class java.lang.String]) does not exist

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am spark dataframe with below schema.

```
-root
 |-- ME_KE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CSPD_CAT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EFF_DT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TER_DT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CREATE_DTM: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ELIG_IND: string (nullable = true)
```

Basically I am trying to convert spark SQL code into SQL on directly on dataframe.

```
df=spark.read.format('csv').load(SourceFilesPath+"\\cutdetl.csv",infraSchema=True,header=True)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("cutdetl")

spark.sql(f"""select
              me_ke,
              eff_dt,
              ter_dt,
              create_dtm
              from
              cutdetl
              where
              (elig_ind = 'Y') and
              ((to_date({start_dt},'dd-mon-yyyy') between eff_dt and ter_dt) or
              (eff_dt between to_date({start_dt}'dd-mon-yyyy') and to_date({end_dt},'dd-mon-yyyy'))
""")
```

Below is the code I have tried.

```
df1=df.select("me_ke","eff_dt","ter_dt","elig_ind")
      .where(col("elig_ind")=="Y" & (F.to_date('31-SEP-2022', dd-mon-yyyy')
      .between(col("mepe_eff_dt"),col("mepe_term_dt"))) | 
      (F.to_date(col("eff_dt"))
      .between(F.to_date('31-DEC-2022'),F.to_date('31-DEC-2022'))))
```

I am getting below error:

````
py4j.Py4JException: Method and([class java.lang.String]) does not exist``` 

Could anyone help with converting above code to dataframe level SQL
````

Answer (score 0):

I'd go like this

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df=spark.read.format('csv').load(SourceFilesPath+"\\cutdetl.csv",infraSchema=True,header=True)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("cutdetl")

df1 = df.filter(col("elig_ind") == "Y")
df1 = df1.filter((col("eff_dt").between(f"to_date({start_dt},'dd-mon-yyyy')", f"to_date({end_dt},'dd-mon-yyyy')")) | 
               (f"to_date({start_dt},'dd-mon-yyyy')".between(col("eff_dt"), col("ter_dt"))))
df1 = df1.select("me_ke", "eff_dt", "ter_dt", "create_dtm")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Azure databricks and just restarting the cluster worked